# How do I assign a SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, string, asp.net-membership

```
   //Retrieve data to display
   string queryString2 = "SELECT [ConfidenceLevel], [LoveLevel], [StressLevel] FROM [UserData] WHERE ([UserProfileID] = @UserProfileID) ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC";
   SqlCommand CommandSelect = new SqlCommand(queryString2, database.Connection);

   //add parameters. used to prevent sql injection
   CommandSelect.Parameters.Add("@UserProfileID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
   CommandSelect.Parameters["@UserProfileID"].Value = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

So at the very end, instead of using the "Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey" I want to use a dynamic member ID, that I will only have available as a string from the GET name value pair.

i.e. - string id = "a051fc1b-4f51-485b-a07d-0f378528974e "

How do I get this string to be assigned to the last SQL parameter line assigning the value? Type cast it?

If I just assign it the string I recieve the error:

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to
>   'System.Guid'.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CommandSelect.Parameters["@UserProfileID"].Value = 
                                     new Guid(ship.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the documentation for [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).  There you will find a constructor which takes a string value, and creates a Guid struct.

Comment: And to give the answer here, instead of forcing readers to follow the link, i can reveal that creating a Guid from string is done like *new Guid(string)*